# How to force xscreensaver to stay on top?

Tags: linux, window, window-manager, xscreensaver

I am building web kiosek and I am using `matchbox` as window manager and `xscreensaver`. My problem is that I need in background restart web browser, but when xscreensaver goes to blank and browser is restarted, then that browser is on top of screen and xscreensaver is hidden behind it - I have to do `xscreensaver-command -deactivate/-activate` to make him cover screen again.

I tried `wmctrl`, which doesn't work (at least not referencing by window id), and had hope for `xdotool`, but still unsuccessfully.

From xscreensaver FAQ http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/faq.html#popup-windows it seems that problem is this:

> mapping windows with XRestackWindows instead of XRaiseWindow, to ensure that managed windows always appear below override-redirect windows"

So, should I change window manager, or is a workaround with tool like xdotool to find xscreensaver windows and move them on top of window stack?

Answer (score 0):

So, after testing many light window managers (aewm, flvm, openbox...), which none of them helped, I found i3wm which behave as expected - xscreensaver stay on top of screen and any open window stay in background hidden behind. Only problem is that it is tiling wm and it will have many and many keyboard shortcuts and such, so I have to eliminate them all.